# Definite integral involve Gaussian $\int_0^{s_0} dt\ t^n e^{-(t-a)^2}$

Tags: integration

Consider the following integral with non integer $n$
$$\int_0^{s_0} dt\ t^n e^{-(t-a)^2}$$

For $s_0=\infty$, Mathematica give

```
ConditionalExpression[1/2 E^-a^2 (a n Gamma[n/2] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + n/2, 3/2, a^2] + 
Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + n)/2, 1/2, a^2]), Re[n] > -1]
```

But for $s_0\neq\infty$, is there any way to evaluate this integral?

Comment: I suppose that the result you gave is for $a>0$

Comment: For non-integer $n$, a closed form is not likely. An approximate expression could probably be found though... if you tell us what parameters you are interested in, eg. large $s_0$? small $a$?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\limits_0^s t^n\exp(-(t-a)^2)\,dt$$
$\displaystyle u=t-a\Rightarrow du=dt\qquad t\in[0,s]\mapsto u\in[-a,s-a]$
$$I=\int\limits_{-a}^{s-a} (u+a)^n\exp(-u^2)\,du$$
$\displaystyle (u+a)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}u^ka^{n-k}$
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}\int\limits_{-a}^{s-a}u^k\exp(-u^2)\,du$$
$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{s-a}f(u)\,du=\int_{-a}^0f(u)\,du+\int_0^{s-a}f(u)\,du
\\\displaystyle=\int_0^af(-u)\,du+\int_0^{s-a}f(u)\,du$

$\displaystyle\therefore\int_{-a}^{s-a}u^k\exp(-u^2)\,du=(-1)^k\int_0^au^k\exp(-u^2)\,du+\int_0^{s-a}u^k\exp(-u^2)\,du$

Now consider using the substitution $v=u^2$ and the definition of the lower incomplete gamma function. However, note that this relies on $n\in\mathbb{Z},|s|<\infty$

---

In the end this expression came out for me as:
$$\cfrac12\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}\left[(-1)^k\gamma\left(\cfrac{k+1}{2},\sqrt{a}\right)+\gamma\left(\cfrac{k+1}{2},\sqrt{s-a}\right)\right]$$
so I'm not sure this is much better and it has limitations on values of $n$